# Problem with trying to pass object data from function in JS

Tags: javascript

I am doing some JS challenges and am a stuck on one of the questions, for some reason the function argument isn't available and its blank in VS code and getting some unexpected results.

```
function myFunction(a, b) {

    return {a:b}
    
}

console.log(myFunction('b','w'))

//Expected result {b:'w'}

//What I am getting in console {a: 'w'}
```

Comment: `for some reason the function argument isn't available and its blank in VS code` why do you assume that they are empty? `b` holds clearly `w` as value based on your output. And you don’t use `a` .

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to dynamically set your key. Try this.

```
function myFunction(a,b) {
    return {[a]:b};
}

console.log(myFunction('b','w'))
```